# Can't access to methods that added via Prototype to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i have this object declaration inside an `Angular.js` module:

```
    $scope.test=function(){

    };

    $scope.test.prototype.push = function(data) {
        return data;
    };
```

And i call it like this:

```
var a = $scope.test.push(1);
console.error(a);
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$scope.test.push(1)')
```

Why i cant access to methods that i added via `Prototype` to my object?

Comment: The `test` becomes accessible from objects that you create using `test` as a constructor function, not from the function object itself, unless you did `$scope.test.prototype.push(1);`, which would be strange. You can add the `push` function directly to the `$scope.test` function if you wish, but I'm not sure what you're after in the end.

Comment: You probably want `var a = new $scope.test.push(1);` and if so the convention would be to name Test from capital letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mistaking a function's prototype *property* with the internal prototype of an object.

A relevant quote from the book [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html):

> It is important to note the distinction between the way a prototype is associated with a constructor (through its `prototype` property) and the way objects *have* a prototype (which can be retrieved with `Object.getPrototypeOf`). The actual prototype of a constructor is `Function.prototype` since constructors are functions. Its `prototype` *property* will be the prototype of instances created through it but is not its *own* prototype.

What this means in the context of your code sample:

```
$scope.test.prototype.push = function(data) {
    return data;
};
```

Here you've added a push function to the prototype property of the `$scope.test` function, which will be present on the prototype of objects created by using this test function as a constructor function (with the `new` keyword).

`$scope.test`, however, remains an empty function, which has no `.push()` method, resulting in the error. If you want to add a push method to *every* function, you could use Function.prototype (note that Function is the constructor with which new functions are created), but I'm not sure where are we going with this.

Comment: i just wanted to add new method to that object. i was thinking prototype is  the way, but right now i remove it and code works! $scope.test.push = function (data) {...   i don't know it's the proper way by the way.